# Ошибка в action в React+redux - приложении после получения response

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-mvc, redux

У меня есть фронтенд на ReactJS, backend на java.
После получения ответа с использованием fetch, получаю ошибку

> Error: Unexpected input given to normalize. Expected type to be
>   "object", found "undefined".

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/overtimes/divisions"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List getAllDivisions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Payment> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(new Payment());
    return res;
}
```

front-end api

```
export const fetchDivisions = () => invokeGetDivisions()
  .then(throwHttpErrors)
  .then(response =>
    response.json(),
  );

    const invokeGetDivisions = () => fetch("/rest/overtimes/divisions", {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
  method: "GET",
  credentials: "same-origin",
});
```

состояние стейта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В системе оказался редьюсер, который принимает такие же actions(совпали полностью type). Дальше неверный парсинг полученных данных и ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте следующее

```
export const fetchDivisions = () => invokeGetDivisions()
  .then(throwHttpErrors)
  .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
```

Comment: Та же ошибка, но содержимое поля data изменилось на это data
:
"[{},[{}]]"